# How to check if username exist before adding in the system using Selenium Webdriver and C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium and C#. I need help. Thanks
How to check if username exists before adding in the system using Selenium Webdriver and C#

Comment: Please edit your question to give more information: without knowing how your system actually works, it's not possible to give you anything more than general guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Two choices:

Black box.  If you don't have access to the program environment and don't have the ability to check behind the scene with database calls then you need to do what a regular user would do - use the system.  Write a test that tries to a user and verify that you get the error message that the user already exists.  If necessary use the web interface to add a user and then use it again to try adding the user again and verify that you get the user already exists error message.

White Box.  If you have at least some access to program internals or the database you can use those approaches to check if a user exists or add a user as desired before using the web application